# eclipse cdt change object file extension for C++ files

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have two files in the same folder, foo.c and foo.cpp (not my code and cannot easily be changed).  Eclipse CDT compiles them both to foo.o, which obviously causes problems.

I'd like to change the default object file extension for C++ files to .opp instead of .o.  I tried changing the Command Line Pattern to append a "pp" to the ${OUTPUT}, but eclipse doesn't see that or understand, so when it goes to create the library, it doesn't include the .opp file.

Thanks

Comment: Easy:  change `foo.c` to `foo_c.c`.  Hard:  change `foo.o` to `foo.opp`.